Does Google Search index direct download links?
Does google index direct download links the likes of which you can find on file download sites? I searched for some specific links on Google but couldn't find them.

What type of content is at these download links?   Like software and other binary files?

@StephenOstermiller Yes, all kinds of files. The way they work (usually) is you paste the link in the browser and the download starts immediately.

There are two HTTP headers that will start downloads automatically: content-disposition: attachment and content-type:application/octet-stream.  There may be separate answers to this question based on which of the two is used.
